# Database Options has an unresolved reference to Filegroup [FILESTREAM]

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

A previous iteration of a SQL Server Data Tools project in my Visual Studio solution utilized FileTables/FILESTREAM.  The codebase has since been refactored to not use FileTables so I removed all files that referenced that feature.  I'm now getting this error when I try to rebuild the project:

> Error 367 SQL71501: Database Options has an unresolved reference to
>   Filegroup [FILESTREAM]. Remove the reference using the project
>   settings page of the project's properties.

Following the error message's instructions, I go into Project Properties > Project Settings > Database Settings and remove as many references to FILESTREAM as possible.  I'm still getting this error message, however.  How to I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A colleague informed me of the fix for this...  If you are getting a build error for the database project, specifically an unresolved reference to the storage [FILESTREAM], close the solution or unload the offending database project, go into the project's folder and delete the file *.dbmdl.

Comment: I also needed to remove the `<DefaultFileStreamFilegroup>` tag out of the `sqlproj` file.

Comment: I had to also delete the Bin and Obj folders